# Calling heroku API from React app, error 200

Tags: reactjs, heroku, axios, cors, fetch

I created a small API that scrapes a web page for train arrival/departures. I hosted it on Heroku and when i visit the page: https://sl-scraper.herokuapp.com/fromstockholm i can see the JSON response i expect. It looks like this: [image]

Everything fine so far. Now i am looking to get this data in my React app to display it in a nicer way. This is where i run into problem. I tried to get the information in two ways, and both ways causes the same issue.

Here is the first attempt:

```
React.useEffect(function(){
    axios.get("https://sl-scraper.herokuapp.com/fromstockholm")
    .then(response =>{
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },[]);
```

Here is the second attempt:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://sl-scraper.herokuapp.com/fromstockholm")
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },[]);
```

Both these attempts causes this issue when i inspect the log:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sl-scraper.herokuapp.com/fromstockholm' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image]

Does anyone know why i get these errors? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I see errors in your screenshot, but FYI [HTTP 200 Ok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success) indicates _success_, not an error. I'm not sure where you're seeing a 200 response, but that probably isn't where the problem is.

Comment: @Chris Okay, i uploaded the React app to Netlify and tried to run it. I get the same error.. Would you mind taking a look at the latest answer? I updated it there.

Answer (score 0):

**Cloning the CORS-Anywhere repo to our PC**

we have our environment set up we can proceed to clone the [CORS-Anywhere repo](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/) into a selected destination on our PC.

As a developer, it is always nice to appreciate the effort of other developers that provide solutions that make our lives easier by sending some form of support in their direction, so do drop a star for the CORS-Anywhere repo if it helps you solve your problem.

To start, we will open our terminal at the directory of the local storage we want to place the CORS-Anywhere server in locally and run the git command:

> git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

After the cloning is complete we will have to install all the packages this project depends on by running the command *npm install* on your terminal:

> npm install

After that deploy your heroku app.

Reference: https://dev.to/imiebogodson/fixing-the-cors-error-by-hosting-your-own-proxy-on-heroku-3lcb

Comment: Will this make me able to get the information from the API only locally? Do you know how it will be if i deploay this React app? Will it work there as well?

"we will open our terminal at the directory of the local storage we want to place the CORS-Anywhere server in locally " - What do you mean by this? How do i know what directory i want to place the CORS-Anywhere in?

Comment: @Brewsli This issue is not happed in live. no worries. It happens because of localhost. 
For more details you can refer the blog that I add in answer.

Comment: Actually i hosted my React app on Netlify and the same error occurs. I will show you in a new post.